# Extra word appended to smart substring algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a CareerCup question:

> "Smart substring"  Write a function that takes maximum 30 characters
>   from a string but without cutting the words.
>
> Full description:  "Featuring stylish rooms and moorings for
>   recreation boats, Room Mate Aitana is a designer hotel built in 2013
>   on an island in the IJ River in Amsterdam."
>
> First 30 characters:  "Featuring stylish rooms and mo"
>
> Smarter approach (max 30 characters, no words are broken):  "Featuring
>   stylish rooms and"

Here is my code. My logic is, I only append the string if after the appending, it is less than 30 characters.

```
public static String substring(String sentence) {
    StringBuffer subString = new StringBuffer();
    String[] splitStr = sentence.split(" ");
    for(String s : splitStr){
        if(subString.append(" " + s).length() < 30) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return subString.toString();
        }
    }
    return subString.toString();
}
```

This is my input:

```
    String s = "Featuring a stylish room thatsssss is almost";
    System.out.println("Count: " + substring(s).length());
    System.out.println("Result: " + substring(s));
```

Output:

```
Count: 35
Result:  Featuring a stylish room thatsssss
```

The fifth word `thatsssss` is tripping my algorithm up, but I guess that makes sense because in the `else-statement`, the word is already appended in the conditional check.

My question is - how do I both check for the conditional of *after the appending* and have it not append in the return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't split the string and rebuild it, just find last space before (or at) the cutoff point, using `lastIndexOf()`.

```
public static String truncate(String text, int length) {
    if (text == null || text.length() <= length)
        return text;
    int idx = text.lastIndexOf(' ', length);
    return text.substring(0, (idx != -1 ? idx : length));
}
```

As for performance, the search is `O(5.1)` (average word length is 5.1), and the substring is `O(1)` for Java 1-6, and `O(n)` for Java 7+ (copies the `char[]`), with `n` being the max. length. Implementation using `split()` would also be `O(n)`, but with `n` being the full text length, so this method is *much* faster.

*Test*

```
String text = "Featuring stylish rooms and moorings for recreation boats, Room Mate Aitana is a designer hotel built in 2013 on an island in the IJ River in Amsterdam.";
for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d: %s%n", i, truncate(text, i));
}
```

*Output*

```
 0: 
 1: F
 2: Fe
 3: Fea
 4: Feat
 5: Featu
 6: Featur
 7: Featuri
 8: Featurin
 9: Featuring
10: Featuring
11: Featuring
12: Featuring
13: Featuring
14: Featuring
15: Featuring
16: Featuring
17: Featuring stylish
18: Featuring stylish
19: Featuring stylish
20: Featuring stylish
21: Featuring stylish
22: Featuring stylish
23: Featuring stylish rooms
24: Featuring stylish rooms
25: Featuring stylish rooms
26: Featuring stylish rooms
27: Featuring stylish rooms and
28: Featuring stylish rooms and
29: Featuring stylish rooms and
30: Featuring stylish rooms and
31: Featuring stylish rooms and
32: Featuring stylish rooms and
33: Featuring stylish rooms and
34: Featuring stylish rooms and
35: Featuring stylish rooms and
36: Featuring stylish rooms and moorings
37: Featuring stylish rooms and moorings
38: Featuring stylish rooms and moorings
39: Featuring stylish rooms and moorings
40: Featuring stylish rooms and moorings for
```

Comment: I am having trouble following the ternary operator within the return statement. Can you briefly explain what that does?

Comment: Look at the test output. For length 0 to 8, there is no space to break on, so `lastIndexOf()` returns `-1`, and the expression falls back to just return a partial word, i.e. using the requested `length`.

Answer (score 3):

Why is your if like this ?

```
    if(subString.append(" " + s).length() < 30)
```

Here you are appending s to the string even if the length is going to be greater than 30. Say you current length is 28 and the next word is test. So it's going to append test to your subString then check it's size which is going to be greater than 30 so it will go to the else branch. But it will be too late since it already appended the test word. So to fix this you should check if the current word size is going to make your substring size greater than 30 as follow

```
    if(subString.length() + s.length() + 1 <= 30){
        subString.append(" "+s.length());
    } else {
     ...  //same code
    }
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it.

Comment: also, I guess it should be `<= 30`, since the specs says *max 30 characters*

Comment: Also, this should be `O(n)` yes?

Comment: Yes it's is basically the same as your previous code the if is constant O(1) because basically is just addition and the StringBuilder takes O(n) so your overall performance is O(n).

Comment: Are there any benefits to my solution vs the first answer on here: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5156072660664320

Comment: @theGreenCabbage No, because your code wastes time splitting the *entire* string into pieces, copying the `char[]` for each word, then builds up the final string by copying the characters 2 times again in the `" " + s` expression, and once more in the `append()` call, and finally again in the `toString()` call. Each character is copied 5(!) times, whereas the linked answer copies twice (2 `substring()` calls), and my answer only copies once.

Comment: @Andreas I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can do it like this:

> Algorithm: Don't try to break or join string, simply just check the
> find the index of space before the word at index k

```
function main(str = "You have to rise and shine even in the darkness", k = 19) 
{
  let idx = str.lastIndexOf(" ", k);
  const smartSubStr = str.substring(0, idx);
  return smartSubStr;
}
main();
```